# Product Specs Review

Tags: user-stories, agile-processes

Im currently a Product Manager in a agile project, we have 4  dev teams with a PM in every team. Due to repeating mistakes among integration between the PM's (one story affects another with both sides don't realize it until delivery time).
I was wondering in there a mechanism like a story "pull request" in your company? If so, what are the stages? Who is involved? If not, what do you recommended avoiding those mistakes?

Comment: If you are into scrum, then 'scrum of scrums' might be what you are looking for - https://www.agilealliance.org/glossary/scrum-of-scrums/

Answer (score 2):

A good way to tackle this problem is to strive for [independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INVEST_(mnemonic)#Independent) user stories. Independent stories are much simpler to handle in a multi-team environment.

It is also worth ensuring you have just one backlog for each product. This can be done even if you have several teams working on that product. With just one backlog it is easier to identify and flag any dependencies.

Comment: What if thw story itself is independent, But behind the scene it affects other stories? We had a transtaction from waterfall to agile

Comment: If the teams think that stories are independent, but they turn out not to be, then I would suggest this is a topic to be discussed at your retrospectives. Perhaps there is a way of better identifying dependencies?

Answer (score -1):

I strongly agree with Barnaby Golden's two points.

Adding to that, try to not fall into the trap to assume that the underlying technical aspects of a business requirement affect only a single team or a single technical domain. You do not know. Often the technical experts themselves do not know at first glance, so how can you?

In my current assignment invites to our refinement meetings (where new requirements and business user stories are presented and discussed with IT) *must* be sent to all teams.

Usually at least one expert of each team reads the user stories well before the meeting and discusses with his peers if they need to join the refinement meeting or if the story *really* doesn't affect them.

If during the meeting it becomes clear that a team will be affected that is not present, it is encouraged to try to pull a member of that team into the meeting spontaneously.

That way the decision of which teams are affected by a requirement is being made by the experts, the teams.

We also use a Scrum of Scrum to catch any unforeseen dependencies between teams, as mentioned by Barnaby Golden.

Maybe have a look at scaled Scrum principles with Nexus, SaFE or less to get more information on how to handle multi-team development challenges.